# need assessment with CSS/ padding-bottom/ li

Tags: html, css

I made an ul li that looks like this:

```
  TRAVEL | BY JACK BLUE | OCTOBER 12, 2014 10:30 PM
```

Anyhow those line between the li data are made with border-right, and I have a picture that I put beneath that li above, **now my problem is when I try to put padding-bottom to the li to make space between the li data and img, it also makes those borders you see longer, and I want them the way they are even with the padding/ space; so any idea?**

This is my CSS code:

```
.topicMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    color: #969696;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 0 95px;
    height: 5px;
}
.topicMenu li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid #969696;
}
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="topicMenu">
    <ul>
        <li style="padding-left: 0;"><a href="" class="ulink">Travel</a></li>
        <li><a href="">By Jack Blue</a></li>
        <li style="border-right: none;">October 12, 2014 10:30 pm</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<img src="images/nap-place.jpg" />
```

Comment: User margin instead of padding.

Comment: Please edit your question title to a question and not a list of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use margin-bottom instead. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m0nk3y/b9jojgrj/

```
.topicMenu li {
        float: left;
        padding: 0 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border-right: 1px solid #969696;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, it works perfectly and properly now

Comment: @user3586095 if this works for you please accept this as the answer. Thank you.